# How to read PDF files and xml files in Apache Spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

My sample code for reading text file is

```
val text = sc.hadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], sc.defaultMinPartitions)
    var rddwithPath = text.asInstanceOf[HadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]].mapPartitionsWithInputSplit { (inputSplit, iterator) ⇒
      val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
      iterator.map { tpl ⇒ (file.getPath.toString, tpl._2.toString) }
    }.reduceByKey((a,b) => a)
```

In this way how can I use PDF and Xml files

Comment: you can use Tika as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PDF & XML can be parsed using Tika:

look at [Apache Tika - a content analysis toolkit](http://tika.apache.org/)
[image]
look at 
- https://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/parser/xml/
- http://tika.apache.org/0.7/api/org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/PDFParser.html
- https://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/parser/AutoDetectParser.html
Below is example integration of Spark with Tika :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream
import org.apache.tika.metadata._
import org.apache.tika.parser._
import org.apache.tika.sax.WriteOutContentHandler
import java.io._

object TikaFileParser {

  def tikaFunc (a: (String, PortableDataStream)) = {

    val file : File = new File(a._1.drop(5))
    val myparser : AutoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser()
    val stream : InputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
    val handler : WriteOutContentHandler = new WriteOutContentHandler(-1)
    val metadata : Metadata = new Metadata()
    val context : ParseContext = new ParseContext()

    myparser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context)

    stream.close

    println(handler.toString())
    println("------------------------------------------------")
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val filesPath = "/home/user/documents/*"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TikaFileParser")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val fileData = sc.binaryFiles(filesPath)
    fileData.foreach( x => tikaFunc(x))
  }
}
```

Comment: yes thank you so much . Also one more doubt if I give hdfs path will it work ?

for example : path ="hdfs://namenode2.aibl.net:8020/ABDF/akhilaajith/PF_knnmodel_1231480046927236/visualise1/model_points"
its showing error message because double // removed from that path . How to overcome this ?

Comment: If I want corresponding filename with its record , then how can I modify this code ? 
doc1.txt,first record
doc1.txt,secondrecord
doc2.txt,firstrecord 
like this

Comment: plz help me to figure out

Comment: you can use `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles` which returns an `RDD` of (filename,content). later you can change the content to binary type and pass it to tika function. note for wholetextfiles files should be not too big check docs for this.

Comment: binaryFiles also has the same signature just now I checked `def
binaryFiles(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[(String, PortableDataStream)]
 Permalink
Get an RDD for a Hadoop-readable dataset as PortableDataStream for each file (useful for binary data)

For example, if you have the following files:

hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00000
hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00001
...
hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn
Do val rdd = sparkContext.binaryFiles("hdfs://a-hdfs-path"),

then rdd contains
(a-hdfs-path/part-00000, its content)
...
(a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn, its content)`

Comment: see this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@binaryFiles(String,Int):RDD[(String,String)])

Comment: yes I got that answer. but My question is can I print each record along with its filename like  what I mentioned earlier. I want the data in that format . not like doc1.txt,fullcontent
doc2.txt,fullcontent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136234/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-akhilav).

Comment: Does this work even for the non English characters like table,Mathematical formulas ,Hindi language or any other language in PDF..

Comment: @ThePowerHouse  refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869104/647053) I havent tried foreign characters you need to do a small POC on this

Comment: has anyone figured out how to read from hdfs , i'm having an issue while submitting the rdd to Tika function.

Comment: It seems the spark job fails with fileNotFoundException:

  def pdfRead(fileNameFromRDD: (String, PortableDataStream), sparkSession: SparkSession) = {

    val file: File = new File(fileNameFromRDD._1.drop(5))

    val document = PDDocument.load(file); //this line throws error java.io.FileNotFoundException

How do I use an hdfs file with org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument ?

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram The hdfs location is correct. Something wrong is happening when I'm trying to load the file as a PDDocument.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram When I run this job in local it works but not when submitted on cluster. Did your code work when submitted on the cluster? I've submitted a question in so with details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546241/text-from-pdf-in-spark

Answer (score 4):

PDF can be parse in pyspark as follow:

If PDF is store in HDFS then using sc.binaryFiles() as PDF is store in binary format.
Then the binary content can be send to pdfminer for parsing.

```
import pdfminer
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument

def return_device_content(cont):
    fp = io.BytesIO(cont)
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    document = PDFDocument(parser)

filesPath="/user/root/*.pdf"
fileData = sc.binaryFiles(filesPath)
file_content = fileData.map(lambda content : content[1])
file_content1 = file_content.map(return_device_content)
```

Further parsing is can be done using functionality provided by pdfminer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use spark-shell with tika and run the below code in a sequential manner or in a distributed manner depending upon your use case

```
spark-shell --jars tika-app-1.8.jar
val binRDD = sc.binaryFiles("/data/")
val textRDD = binRDD.map(file => {new org.apache.tika.Tika().parseToString(file._2.open( ))})
textRDD.saveAsTextFile("/output/")
System.exit(0)
```