# Text From PDF in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract text from pdf files in hdfs using pdfBox.

However it throws an error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: ...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /nnAlias:8020/tmp/sample.pdf 
(No such file or directory)"
```

What am I missing? Should I be working with PortableDataStream instead of the string part of:

`val files: RDD[(String, PortableDataStream)]`?

```
def pdfRead(fileNameFromRDD: (String, PortableDataStream), sparkSession: SparkSession) = {
val file: File = new File(fileNameFromRDD._1.drop(5))
val document = PDDocument.load(file); //It throws an error here.

if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
  val stripper = new PDFTextStripper()
  val text = stripper.getText(document)
  println("Text:" + text)

}
    document.close()

  }

//This is where I call the above pdf to text converter method.
     val files = sparkSession.sparkContext.binaryFiles("hdfs://nnAlias:8020/tmp/sample.pdf")
    files.foreach(println)

    files.foreach(f => println(f._1))

    files.foreach(fileStream => pdfRead(fileStream, sparkSession))
```

Comment: "/nnAlias:8020/tmp/sample.pdf" does not look like a file name to me, or is this some new type of path that I missed?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It's the <nameNode High Availability Alias Name>:<NameNode port> along with the actual path. When I do hadoop fs -ls hdfs://nnAlias:8020/tmp/sample.pdf, it works. If I don't use the nameNode alias and port, it complains saying unknown host /tmp.

Comment: Yes but is that a valid file name for `new File()`? Or ist this some sort of URL that is only valid in the Hadoop world?