# Read pdf file in apache spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

We can read avro file using the below code,

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(path)
```

is it possible to read pdf files using Spark dataframes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read PDF files and xml files in Apache Spark scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000832/how-to-read-pdf-files-and-xml-files-in-apache-spark-scala)

Comment: Thank you, I want to know is it possible to read pdf files using Spark dataframes

Comment: I think that currently you need to read the data as a binary file (RDD) and then convert it to a dataframe. See the relevant JIRA issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read a pdf and store in a df as it will cannot interrupt the columns of the dataframe(basically it doens't have a **standard schema**), so if you want to get some data from a pdf first convert that to csv or parquet and then you can read from that file and then create a dataframe as it has a defined schema

visit this gitbook to understand more on what are the available read formats which you can use to get the data as a Dataframe

[DataFrameReader — Loading Data From External Data Sources](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-DataFrameReader.html#load)