# How to read the pdf file in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pdf, hadoop2

By using Spark I want to read the PDF file which contains data in a table format and result should be in the structured data format (to store it in the database)

can suggest any of the frameworks read the pdf file and result should be in the structure data

PDF format looks like this 
[click to view](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf%20file%20in%20tabular%20format&rlz=1C1CHWA_enIN782IN782&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpkf2O3cnhAhXt73MBHf7IC40Q_AUIDygC&biw=1510&bih=690#imgrc=qZPKlqq5daW9GM:)

expected result should be in tabular format

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000832/how-to-read-pdf-files-and-xml-files-in-apache-spark-scala
Please check and close the question.